# Light boxes troubles

Tags: fallout-4

I have connected all my settlement up and all lights are working fine however, when I set up my light boxes on a 1 seconds on 1 seconds off or so on, my light circulation do the same even when they are not connected. How do I keep my lights on, but put my light boxes on a timer with out it affecting the rest. ?

Comment: Not 100% clear on what the problem is. It sounds like you have some lights that are *not* supposed to be cycling, and some that *are*, but they're *all* cycling. Is that right? How do you have things wired together? Is there any connection between the two sets of lights?

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that both sets of lights are on separate circuits.

So, for example, have all your normal lights connected to on set of generators in the settlement, then create a separate detached generator, and connect the terminal and light boxes to that generator.